# Converting ... in function into joining variables

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following function (simplified) that joins two dataframes (in the example, I am using the same dataframes):

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

test_data <- tibble(A = c(1,2), B = c("A", "C"), C = c("f", "m"))
    
    myfunction <- function(mydata, ...) {
      mydata %>% 
        left_join(mydata, by = ...)
    }
    
    myfunction(test_data, B, C)
```

This produces an error. I need the ... in my original rather complex function to group the dataframe, so I would like to keep the ...

Any idea how to do this?

Cheers

Renger

Comment: You can try using `left_join(mydata, by = join_by(...))`.

Comment: Well for starters, you cannot pass multiple package names to `library()`.

Comment: @Konrad: yes, I know, but I am so used to p_load from the package pacman, that I forgot :-)

Comment: @RitchieSacramento if you could expand upon why that works but OP's doesn't (in the context of an answer I'd really appreciate that! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, it's not the `...` that is causing the error, it's that the `by` argument expects either a character vector or a join specification created by `join_by()`.  If you pass your function a character vector, it works:

```
myfunction(test_data, c("B", "C"))

# A tibble: 2 × 4
    A.x B     C       A.y
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 A     f         1
2     2 C     m         2
```

If you want to pass column names as symbols, you can use `join_by(...)` in your function which has tidy dots support meaning that non standard evaluation is handled for you:

```
myfunction <- function(mydata, ...) {
  mydata %>% 
    left_join(mydata, by = join_by(...))
}

# A tibble: 2 × 4
    A.x B     C       A.y
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 A     f         1
2     2 C     m         2
```

Note you could also use `join_by()` in your original function call, `myfunction(test_data, join_by(B, C))` (if you weren't using dots elsewhere in your function).